# finding duplicate rows in excel and export those rows to another sheet using power shell

Tags: c#, excel, powershell, oledb, oledbconnection

How to find duplicate values in Excel and export rows to another sheet using power shell?
[image]
I had an Excel sheet with multiple rows and column lets say from "A" to "k". I need to find duplicate rows only if values in all the columns in a row are unique. And the script should ignore D,E,F columns even though those column's values are same.

**The script should also copy all those duplicate rows and should paste in a new excel file.it should also copy header row and source of duplicate rows** and  Also attaching a sample image of input file(the output file should also be same as input in this input case because it should also copy source duplicate rows). I had tried a code but it is throwing an error..please look into that and give me a solution for the code.

```
code:
# The Text OleDB driver is only available in PowerShell x86. Start x86 
shell if using x64.
# This has to be the first check this script performs.
if ($env:Processor_Architecture -ne "x86")   { 
Write-Warning "Switching to x86 shell"
&"$env:windir\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
"$PSCommandPath $args"; return 
 }

# Change to your CSV file name, must end in .csv or .tsv
$csvfile = "C:\files\A01modcsv.csv"

 # Does the first row contain column names?
 $firstRowColumns = $True

 # What's the delimiter? Use `t for tabbed.
 $csvdelimter = "`t"


 $firstRowColumns = $true
 $checkColumns = "A"


 $datasource = Split-Path $csvfile
 $tablename = (Split-Path $csvfile -leaf).Replace(".","#")

 switch ($firstRowColumns) {
     $true { $firstRowColumns = "Yes" }
     $false { $firstRowColumns = "No" }
  }

 $elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 
 [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data")

  # Setup OleDB using Microsoft Text Driver.
  $connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$datasource;Extended Properties='text;HDR=$firstRowColumns;FMT=Delimited($csvdelimter)';"

$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDB.OleDBCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn


 # Perform select on CSV file, then add results to a datatable using ExecuteReader
 $sql = "SELECT $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount FROM [$tablename] GROUP BY $checkColumns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
 $cmd.CommandText = $sql
 $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
 $dt.BeginLoadData()
$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehaviour]::CloseConnection))
 $dt.EndLoadData()
 $totaltime = [math]::Round($elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds,2)

 # Get Total Row Count

 $cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRows FROM [$tablename]"
 $totalrows = $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
 $conn.Close()[enter image description here][1]

# Output some stats
$dupecount = $dt.Rows.Count
Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $totaltime seconds. $dupecount duplicates found out of $totalrows total rows. You can access these dupes using `$dt." -ForegroundColor Green
```

> I am getting an error in the menctioned code at "$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehaviour]::CloseConnection))" command....can any help me in solving this error.Thank you.

Comment: Could you quote the error?

Comment: i am getting error as "unable to find type [system.data.commandbehaviour] at the above specified error line.I am using powershell *86.should i import any module for this operation to happen..i am not getting what to do for that error...?